# How to Use Where with Many to Many Comparison

Tags: linq, entity-framework, lambda

I have problem with LINQ Query in following scenario:

I have Activity and ActivityTeacher Two Table and List of Some Teachers.

```
 Activity Table

  ActivityID      Date        Class
  1            4/4/2012      1
  2            4/5/2013      2
  3            4/6/2013      5
  4            5/6/2013      2
  5            5/16/2013     1
  6            5/20/2013     8
  7            5/21/2013     7
  8            6/22/2013     6
  9            8/10/2013     5
  10           8/12/2013     4


  ActivityTeacher Table

  ActivityID      TeacherID
  1                  2
  1                  3
  1                  4                 
  2                  6
  3                  6
  3                  6
  3                  4
  2                  5
  4                  2
  4                  3
  4                  6
  5                  8
  5                  7
  5                  6
  6                  6
  6                  7
  6                  9
  6                  10
  6                  1
  6                  2
  7                  2
  7                  8
  7                  9
  7                  10
  8                  3
  8                  4
  8                  6
  8                  7
  9                  10
  9                  3
  9                  2
  10                 1
  10                 2
```

List of Teachers={2,3,4}
Now I want to select records from Activity based on List of Teachers={2,3,4}
without using foreach loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Activity` entity should have a `Teachers` navigation property you can utilize:

```
context.Activities
       .Where(x => listOfTeachers.Contains(x.Teachers.Select(t => t.TeacherId)));
```

If `listOfTeachers` contains the three IDs 2, 3, 4, this query should translate to SQL that is similar to the following:

```
select a.*
from Activity a
  inner join ActivityTeacher at
      on a.activityid = at.activityid
where at.teacherid in (2, 3, 4);
```

Comment: The downvoter is encouraged to leave a comment. Otherwise I can't improve the answer. As far as I am aware, this should work if the database has been mapped correctly.

Comment: Use a join operation (complexity _n_) instead of `Where(... Contains)` (complexity _n²_)

Comment: @CédricBignon: The join is already in there, via the navigation property. Contrary to your answer, mine actually contains the filtering requested by the OP. The resulting SQL should be something like this: `select a.* from Activity a inner join ActivityTeacher at on a.activityid = at.activityid where at.teacherid in (items in listOfTeachers);`

Comment: `where at.teacherid in (items in listOfTeachers)` can be improved using another `inner join`.

Comment: @CédricBignon: No, it can't, because that can't be translated to SQL. listOfTeachers doesn't exist in the database.

Comment: @DenialHilgarth My fault.

Comment: @CédricBignon: Updated my answer with the SQL statement that should be generated.

Comment: @ManojPilania: Did you even try what I wrote in my answer? And what kind of a comment is "Please solve my problem" anyway?

Comment: @Henrik: Hm? I don't follow

Comment: I find the misspelling of your first name in @CédricBignon's comment funny.